# Count the number of lines in a Swift String

Tags: swift, unicode, line-endings

After reading a medium sized file (about 500kByte) from a web-service I have a regular Swift String (`lines`) originally encoded in `.isolatin1`. Before actually splitting it I would like to count the number of lines (quickly) in order to be able to initialise a progress bar.

What is the best Swift idiom to achieve this?

I came up with the following:

```
let linesCount = lines.reduce(into: 0) { (count, letter) in
   if letter == "\r\n" {
      count += 1
   }
}
```

This does not look too bad but I am asking myself if there is a shorter/faster way to do it. The `characters` property provides access to a sequence of Unicode graphemes which treat `\r\n` as only one entity. Checking this with all `CharacterSet.newlines` does not work, since `CharacterSet` is not a set of `Character` but a set of `Unicode.Scalar` (a little counter-intuitively in my book) which is a set of *code points* (where \r\n counts as two code points), not *graphemes*. Trying

```
var lines = "Hello, playground\r\nhere too\r\nGalahad\r\n"
lines.unicodeScalars.reduce(into: 0) { (cnt, letter) in
if CharacterSet.newlines.contains(letter) {
    cnt += 1
}
```

}

will count to 6 instead of 3. So this is more general than the above method, but it will not work correctly for CRLF line endings.

Is there a way to allow for more line ending conventions (as in `CharacterSet.newlines`) that still achieves the correct result for CRLF? Can the number of lines be computed with less code (while still remaining readable)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's ok for you to use a Foundation method on an NSString, I suggest using

```
enumerateLines(_ block: @escaping (String, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

Here's an example:

```
import Foundation

let base = "Hello, playground\r\nhere too\r\nGalahad\r\n"
let ns = base as NSString

ns.enumerateLines { (str, _) in
    print(str)
}
```

It separates the lines properly, taking into account all linefeed types, such as "\r\n", "\n", etc:

> Hello, playground
>   here too
>   Galahad

In my example I print the lines but it's trivial to count them instead, as you need to - my version is just for the demonstration.

Comment: You are correct, I could count the lines by enumerating them. This is of course what i eventually will want to do, but I wanted to count the number of lines _quickly_ in order to be able to display a progress indicator. Calling `enumerateLines` twice just for the purpose of counting lines seemed like too much overhead at the time.

Comment: @Patru I don't know any way of doing what you want that would be faster or less expensive than enumerating twice with this Foundation method. It's really fast and isn't expensive at all. If someone has a better solution I will gladly upvote it but sincerely, I think this Foundation method is just what you need. :)

Comment: Just measured that, put the findings in another answer and marked your answer as the correct one. Thanks, now I will have to fix the code, luckily that's just a few lines :-)

Answer (score 7):

As I did not find a generic way to count newlines I ended up just solving my problem by iterating through all the characters using

```
let linesCount = text.reduce(into: 0) { (count, letter) in
     if letter == "\r\n" {      // This treats CRLF as one "letter", contrary to UnicodeScalars
        count += 1
     }
}
```

I was sure this would be a lot faster than enumerating lines for just counting, but I resolved to eventually do the measurement. Today I finally got to it and found ... that I could not have been more wrong.

A 10000 line string counted lines as above in about 1.0 seconds , but counting through enumeration using

```
var enumCount = 0
text.enumerateLines { (str, _) in
    enumCount += 1
}
```

only took around 0.8 seconds and was consistently faster by a little more than 20%. I do not know what tricks the Swift engineers hide in their sleves, but they sure manage to `enumerateLines` very quickly. This just for the record.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following extension

```
extension String {

    var numberOfLines: Int {
        return self.components(separatedBy: "\n").count
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this, a `CharacterSet` which Apple provides, made for this task:

```
let newLines = text.components(separatedBy: .newlines).count - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5 Extension

```
extension String {
    
    func numberOfLines() -> Int {
        return self.numberOfOccurrencesOf(string: "\n") + 1
    }

    func numberOfOccurrencesOf(string: String) -> Int {
        return self.components(separatedBy:string).count - 1
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let testString = "First line\nSecond line\nThird line"
let numberOfLines = testString.numberOfLines() // returns 3
```

Comment: There is no function `String.numberOfOccurrencesOf(string:)` in Foundation or any other Swift framework

Comment: My mistake, I updated the answer to include the needed second extension.