# How to create a long String quickly in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, string

While preparing some long Swift `String` in a Playground for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490920/count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-swift-string/46491196#comment82782726_46491196) I noticed that `String` creation time became very noticeable already for 1000 lines, at least 100 times slower than enumerating these lines, so I began to investigate. Eventually I found two ways to create a long `String` quickly enough (in fact faster than it is possible to enumerate its lines):

```
let line = "I am a line terminated by CRLF\r\n"

let longString = String(repeating: line, count: 1000)
// finishes in about 3 ms on my MacBook Pro

var longString2 = line
for _ in 1...10 {
    longString2 = longString2 + longString2
}
// this will give me 1024 lines in about 7 ms
```

However these two solutions only work if all the lines are exactly identical. The "naïve" way to create a long string of *different* lines as in

```
var longString3 = ""

for i in 1...1000 {
    longString3.append("I am a line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n")
}
// suddenly takes 1.7 *seconds*
```

is way off timing wise.

Given Apples documentation states:

> When a string’s contiguous storage fills up, a new buffer must be
>   allocated and data must be moved to the new storage.
>   String buffers use an exponential growth strategy that makes
>   appending to a string a constant time operation when averaged
>   over many append operations.

one would only assume a slight degradation in construction time. But it gets worse, adding the next 1000 lines (this time using `+=` just to try something else) as in

```
for i in 1001...2000 {
    longString3+="I am a line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n"
}
// takes 5.6 seconds!
```

The next 1000 lines take 8.5 seconds, which indicates a quadratic increase in running time. This would indicate that the buffer gets reallocated and assigned to a new memory area *a linear number of times*.

Well be it, we can help the compiler you might say, but even this does not appear to work. Throwing in

```
longString3.reserveCapacity(50000)
```

after its initialisation changes *nothing* in the running time. Now I am asking myself how the above initialisers manage to create their `Strings` at such a blazing speed.

There is a way to improve this of course. You can initialise your lines in an `Array` and then `join` them, leading to

```
var text = ""
var array = [String]()
array.reserveCapacity(10000)
for i in 1...1000 {
    array.append("I am line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n")
}
text = array.joined(separator: "")
text.count
// with a very disappointing running time of 20.7 seconds for 32893 characters
```

This was rather a schock for me, even slower than the other strategies, but then I tried

```
var text = ""
var array = Array(repeatElement(line, count: 1000))
for i in 1...1000 {
    array[i-1] = "I am line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n"
}
text = array.joined(separator: "")
text.count
// with a much more reasonable 124 ms running time
```

Still not blazingly quick, but acceptable, at least for a Playground.

But now I am asking myself: Is this just happening for Playgrounds? Where does this unpredictable behaviour for seemingly similar code come from? And most importantly: What is the best strategy to create a long `String` quickly in Swift (in a readable way)?

### Update:

Given the comments I decided to run a few more experiments in a console application as follows:

```
import Foundation
import QuartzCore

func executionTimeInterval(block: () -> ()) -> CFTimeInterval {
    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    block();
    let end = CACurrentMediaTime()
    return end - start
}

let line = "I am a line terminated by CRLF\r\n"
var text = ""

let createTime = executionTimeInterval {
    text = String(repeating: line, count: 10000)
}
print("creating 10000 lines through initializer: \(createTime)")

var longString = ""
let unreservedThousandTime = executionTimeInterval {
    for i in 1...1000 {
        longString.append("I am line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n")
    }
}
print("append one thousand lines to empty (unreserved): \(unreservedThousandTime)")

let reservedThousandTime = executionTimeInterval {
    longString = ""
    longString.reserveCapacity(50000)
    for i in 1...1000 {
        longString.append("I am line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n")
    }
}
print("append one thousand lines to empty (reserved): \(reservedThousandTime)")

let secondThousendTime = executionTimeInterval {
    for i in 1001...2000 {
        longString+="I am line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n"
    }
}
print("second thousand lines appended: \(secondThousendTime)")

let thirdThousandTime = executionTimeInterval {
    for i in 2001...3000 {
        longString=longString+"I am line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n"
    }
}
print("third thousand lines appended: \(thirdThousandTime)")

let fourthThousandTime = executionTimeInterval {
    for i in 3001...4000 {
        longString+="I am line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n"
    }
}
print("fourth thousand lines appended: \(fourthThousandTime)")

var strArray = [String]()
let oneThousandJoined = executionTimeInterval {
    for i in 1...1000 {
        strArray.append("I am line \(i) terminated by CRLF\r\n")
    }
    let longString2 = strArray.joined()
}
print("one thousand lines joined: \(oneThousandJoined)")
```

This mostly resulted in the expected results:

```
creating 10000 lines through initializer: 0.000855136197060347
append one thousand lines to empty (unreserved): 0.00150042399764061
append one thousand lines to empty (reserved): 0.0011014249175787
second thousand lines appended: 0.00116470409557223
third thousand lines appended: 0.00800192193128169
fourth thousand lines appended: 0.00095564010553062
one thousand lines joined: 0.0015953469555825
```

Since the times ended up in the low single digit milliseconds they are not entirely consistent, but it is certainly reassuring to know that the "naïve" ways of creating a `String` do perform well in "regular" Swift. There is one notable exception, the third way of creating a long `String` through `+` consistently runs more than 5 times slower than the append-variants.

My problems with the long running times were therefore exclusively related to doing this in a Playground. I consider this question closed but I will open another one specific to Playgrounds, maybe someone can shed some light on this anyways.

Comment: You should test it in a compiled project (in Release mode, with optimization). A Playground is an interactive environment and definitely slow.

Comment: I can accept slow for a Playground, but why does String suddenly exhibit a quadratic behaviour while appending when this is supposed to be an amortised constant operation?

Comment: A Playground does many things which take time, such as (live) updating the result column after each assignment. – So if your *real* problem is how to create a long string quickly then you should do this in a compiled project and forget about the Playground. – If your question is in particular about Playgrounds then you might want to clarify that in the title and in the question.

Comment: Note that with your example of `longString2 = longString2 + longString2`, you're only iterating over `1...10`, so of course it'll be fast compared to the rest. When I try that loop in a playground over `1...1000`, it takes forever, as I'd expect. Regarding the quadratic behaviour you're observing with `+=` and `append`, I would speculate that the playground is keeping its own copy of the string at each iteration (so it can show you live results), so the string buffer is never uniquely referenced and therefore reallocates each time. As Martin says, try it in a compiled (and optimised) project.

Comment: @Hamish Note that I am _doubling_ the length of `longString2` in each iteration, giving me 1024 lines in the end, roughly equivalent to the 1000 lines I got before, but _(surprise)_ 500 times faster.

Comment: @Patru Oh sorry, my bad. I would assume it's quicker primarily because you're doing less (re)allocations (10 vs 1000). But again, in a compiled project, using `append` and `+=` won't have to reallocate each time due to the exponential growth of `String`'s buffer, so these playground comparisons really aren't too useful.